# Wanted: jQuery selector with variable part in the middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-selectors

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="Kees_1_test">test 1</div>
<div id="Kees_12_test">test 2</div>
<div id="Kees_335_test">test 3</div>
```

I would like a selector that selects the divs that look like `$('div[id=Kees_{any number}_test]')`. How can I achieve this?

<sup>Note: the ID's are generated by Asp.Net.</sup>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div[id^=Kees_][id$=_test]')
```

That selector selects all elements that have ids that start with `Kees_` and end with `_test`.

As lonesomeday suggested, you can use `.filter()` to ensure that the middle part contains only numbers. You can combine `.filter()` with the example above:

```
$('div[id^=Kees_][id$=_test]').filter(function() {
    return /^Kees_\d+_test$/.test(this.id);
});
```

That should about as good as it gets. Note that I added `^$` to the regex, this will return false on id's such as `Kees_123_test_foo` also but `Kees_123_test` passes.

Comment: Nice! Is there a way from prevent a match for a div with id `Kees_t3t_test`? So can I enforce the middle part to be a number?

Comment: Love the idea of combining two [] statements. I didn't know that one! :-)

Comment: The `.filter()` function is going to get you there - it's ensuring that only `\d` (digit) characters can be between the two underscores.

Comment: Killed it , My 50 lines of code just vanished with this.

Answer (score 7):

The best solution would be to give all your divs a class and use a class selector:

```
<div id="Kees_1_test" class="Kees_test">test 1</div>
<div id="Kees_12_test" class="Kees_test">test 2</div>
<div id="Kees_335_test" class="Kees_test">test 3</div>
```

Selector:

```
$('div.Kees_test');
```

If this isn't possible, the most legible way would be to use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter):

```
$('div[id^="Kees_"]').filter(function() {
    return /Kees_\d+_test/.test(this.id);
});
```

The `\d+` means "select one or more numbers".

Comment: Nice, maybe we could combine the answers to perform better. Doing a `$('div[id^=Kees_]').filter(...)` perhaps?

Comment: @Kees Yes, you could. It will probably make a reasonable difference as well.

Comment: +1: definitely using a class is the best answer here if at all possible.

Comment: I would have gone for a class at first. It's a natural way to group elements. However, maybe look for a parent element first if you don't want to add extra attributes. The class method makes it more transportable though.

Comment: Getting them by ID is a lot quicker than by class. This may or may not be a consideration.

Comment: @5arx It is if you use an id selector (e.g. `#Kees_1_test`), but not if you use the attribute begins with selector on the id attribute.

Comment: @5arx `Getting them by ID is a lot quicker than by class.` but in this case getting it ID is slower since it has to scan the whole page for attributes that begin with X and than it has to loop through that set and check to see if it ends with Y. Going by class in this situation is 100% better.